Gaussian fit with gap in data
I would like to fit a gaussian on an absorption band, in a reflectance spectra. Problem is, in this part of the spectra I have a gap in my data (blank space on the figure), between approximately 0.85 and 1.3 µm. I really need this gaussian, because after this I would like to compute spectral parameters such as the Full-With Half-Maximum and the area occupied by the gaussian.
Here is the functions I use to perform the gaussian fit (credit to this post) :
def gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma):
    return H + A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

def gauss_fit(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gauss, x, y, p0=[min(y), max(y), mean, sigma])
    return popt

How I apply it :
H, A, x0, sigma = gauss_fit(x, y)

And plot it :
plt.plot(x, y, '.k', label='data')
plt.plot(x, gauss(x, *gauss_fit(x, y)), '-r', label='fit')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (µm)')
plt.ylabel('Reflectance')
plt.legend()

Here is what I get : Gaussian fit with gap in data
As you can see the fit seems to work fine until it reaches the gap.
It would really help me if I could have a clean gaussian fit, bonus points if I can then easily compute the FMWH and the area of the gaussian afterward.
Please note that the solution should not be too case-specific, as I have huge datasets to work on. It should thus be implementable in loops.
The only post I could find talking about this issue is this one, but it did not provide me with a satisfying solution.
It's my first time posting on Stack Overflow, please feel free to ask for any complementary information if needed.
Edit 1
I think Tino D and lastchance answers solved the main problem of my code, it being that I defined a normal gaussian fit instead of a substracted one. I obtain this new fit.
However as you can see it is still not perfect, and it strangely goes beyond y=1 on the right side of the fit. I think the problem now resides in my data itself, so here it is as requested.
I use pandas to manage my data, so the file is in pickle format as I store entire nupy arrays in unique DataFrame cells. For this fit we only need the columns 'Wavelength' and 'Reflectance Normalized'. We also only need part of the spectra, so here is the code I use to sample what I need :
#df_merged is the name of the DataFrame

R0700=FindNearest(df_merged.at[0,'Wavelength'], df_merged.at[0,'Reflectance Normalized'], 0.7, show=True)
R1800=FindNearest(df_merged.at[0,'Wavelength'], df_merged.at[0,'Reflectance Normalized'], 1.8, show=True)

x=df_merged.at[0,'Wavelength'][R0700[1]:R1800[1]]
y=df_merged.at[0,'Reflectance Normalized'][R0700[1]:R1800[1]]

FindNearest is a function of mine I use to find specific values in my arrays, it is defined as the following :
def FindNearest(wl, rf, x, show=False):      # wl = wavelength array ; rf = reflectance array ; x = value to find
    
    wl_dif=np.abs(wl-x)
    idx=np.argmin(wl_dif)
    
# Get reflectance and wavelength values
    
    wl_x=wl[idx]
    rf_x=rf[idx]
    
    if show:
        print("Nearest wavelength :", wl_x, ", Index :", idx, ", Corresponding reflectance :", rf_x)

    
# Values : [0] = nearest wavelength value, [1] = position of nearest value in array 
# (both reflectance and wavelength since same size), [2] = nearest reflectance value
    
    return(wl_x, idx, rf_x)

We almost got this, thanks a lot to you 2 !

Hey and welcome! Would be great if you can post the data as well so others can reproduce the problem.

Are you sure that your initial guess p0 is appropriate? As you have a sort of "subtracted" gaussian, surely H should be estimated as max(y) and A (which is negative here) as -(max(y)-min(y)).

was writing an answer to this right now and the same problem popped up @lastchance. OP, use H - A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

@Victor T, I think after your Edit 1 you have the best Gaussian that will fit that data. If you are unhappy with it then I think it is because the data is not particularly well-described by a Gaussian - it cuts off quite sharply at top-right, whilst a Gaussian is a very smooth and gentle curve. From the physical situation here (reflectance on the y axis) I think you should set H=1 and not leave it as a parameter to be fitted.

As lastchance said and as my comment suggested, you were fitting the wrong curve (or your initial guess was not compatible). The function that you wrote was a normal Gaussian and not a subtracted one. So the following can be used
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma):
    return H - A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))
def gauss_fit(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, x, y, p0=[min(y), max(y), mean, sigma])
    return popt
# generate toydataset
x = np.linspace(0.5, 2, 100)
H, A, x0, sigma = 1, 0.5, 1.2, 0.3
y = gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma) + 0.005 * np.random.normal(size=x.size)
# enerate gap in data
gapStart = int(0.1 * len(x))
gapEnd = int(0.4 * len(x))
xGap = np.concatenate([x[:gapStart], x[gapEnd:]])
yGap = np.concatenate([y[:gapStart], y[gapEnd:]])
popt = gauss_fit(xGap, yGap)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xGap, yGap, label='Gap in data', color='blue')
plt.plot(x, gauss(x, *popt), label='Fit', color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.title("30% missing")
plt.grid()

This results in the following:

Now I did generate the toydata but the idea remains the same. As for the calculations:
H_fit, A_fit, x0_fit, sigma_fit = popt
'''
full width at half maximum taken from here and area calculation here:
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/area-under-gaussian-peak-by-easy-measurements.419285/
'''
FWHM = 2.35 * sigma_fit 
Area = H_fit*FWHM/(2.35*0.3989)
print(f"FWHM = {FWHM}")
print(f"Area = {Area}")

Results:
FWHM = 0.7030608784583746
Area = 0.7486638847495126

Hope this helps!

Edit 1: with data from OP
The badly fitted line that you showed in your example is because you are not passing those x values in the middle.
Alternatively:
popt = gauss_fit(x, y)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label='Gap in data', color='blue')
plt.plot(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100), # resample the x variable
         gauss(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100), *popt), # and calculate
         label='Fit', color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

We can resample the x variable from min to max with 100 points using np.linspace, and also important to pass it to the gaus functions. Results:

I highly recommend to ditch Gaussian or to hard-code H=1 as lastchance suggested. The data on the top right is too different. OR you say that you don't care about these points and that you can cut them out.

Edit 2: setting the upper limit to 1
As you saw from your calculations, the fit went overboard and set the sigma as a minus value (hence the negative values). For the fit it is not important since sigma is raised to the power of 2. In any case, I suggest the followign adjustments to your code, although I still think a Gaussian fit does not make sense:
def gauss(x, A, x0, sigma):
    return 1 - A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))
def gauss_fit(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, x, y)
    return popt

In the above functions, H is being set to 1. There is also no need for the initial guesses, the optimizer finds values automatically.
The code for the plotting stays the same. Results:

This gives the following:
FWHM = 0.5
Area = 0.54

Now we see that the fit prefers sticking with the edges to minimize the error and neglects a good fit on the tail. Which btw is too wide of a tail for a Gaussian fit to begin with (in my eyes). The distribution looks slightly platykurtic. Which we can also confirm by calculating the kurtosis:
mean = np.mean(y)
std = np.std(y, ddof=1)
n = len(y)
kurtosis = (n * (n + 1) * np.sum((y - mean) ** 4) / ((n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3) * std ** 4)) - (3 * (n - 1) ** 2 / ((n - 2) * (n - 3)))
print(kurtosis) # -0.13344688172380037

-0.13 is not that far away from 0, but still I think the fit can be done in a better way.
Reading material: Link
I suggest you open another question on crossvalidated to ask for a recommendation regarding which curve to fit.

Thanks a lot, this almost works ! I edited my post with the new result, there's still a problem but it is much better. I think that now the problem is with the data itself, I provided a link to download it and detailed my data processing as much as possible.

@VictorT from your image I can see that you are generating the fitted data with  the original data (in my code it is called xGap) . In my example, I use x which does not have gaps e.g., gauss(x, *popt).

Yes I do, but my original data has the gap. This is the problem I face, I really do not have any way of accessing the points in the gap because of the instruments I use. Unless there is a way to kind of "guess" the position of the points inside that gap, I'm stuck with this incomplete data.

Edit coming up @VictorT

Just applied your edit to my code. I don't really know how to apply the last advices you gave (ditching the Guassian or hardcoding H=1), or even how to simply pass the x data I have in the middle. Also, I tried to compute the FWMH and the area as you did in your example and I obtained really strange values (FWHM = -26.220069604204753 and Area = -16074.904424096074).

I can edit the post (maybe tomorrow). Have a nice evening @VictorT

@Victor T, you are only using the gaussian in order to compute: "full-width half-Maximum and the area occupied", which you can do with any explicit curve fit. If you take Tino D's curve fit and simply place a cap on it at y=1 then a little bit of maths will allow you to find the area and also the width at a point half way between y=1 and y=ymin. For that much you don't need the full gaussian, just the part to the extent of your data (which Tino D's curve fit does admirably with).

@VictorT I didn't really look at the FWHM and the area after the edit. To say the least the fit does not make sense with a Gaussian. One thing that I want to say is that it is always good to know what you are fitting. When you say that this corresponds to reflectance normalized, it means that values need to be constrained to 1, hence the suggestion of setting H=1. Doing so gives a better/worse fit. Better: it makes sense. Worse: the fit is bad, particularly on the right part. See my edit.

Thanks a lot for your explainations ! You're right, maybe a guassian fit wasn't the way to go in the first place. I will try and find some documentation on what type of fit I should use for these kind of distributions, and follow your advice about posting another question on crossvalidated.  Furthermore as @lastchance said, I only need the FWMH and area, so using another type of fit isn't a problem. I'm new to this whole data processing thing, so thanks to both of you for your help and patience !

@VictorT please don't forget to close this question by accepting the answer, if you think that this answer helped
